# In PHP Dependency Injection, do I need to "require_once" the php file where the dependency is defined?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Taking Fabien Potencier's [example](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection):

```
class User
{
  function __construct($storage)
  {
    $this->storage = $storage;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Assuming the Storage class is defined in a different php file (say, storage.php), do I need to include it in this file where the injection is done via a require_once?

Thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting all your `require`s and `include`s at the head of the file - that certainly a style thing, but for one thing it allows you to see by glancing at the source, what other files are need by your PHP file.

There are two cases:

1. You will only ever use `user.php` and `storage.php` from other files (`app.php` say)
2. There are cases where you will use `user.php` and don't want to worry about remembering to require `storage.php`.

For #1 - you don't need to worry about requires, however there's no significant disadvantage to using `require_once` at the head of your PHP even if most of the time it'll have already been required.

For #2 - you need to use `require_once` at the header since you cannot use `user.php` without `storage.php` and the final page only knows it needs `user.php`.

**short answer:** Use `require_once` to include all dependencies for the code (to allow it to easily be used by other code)

**note:** You should only include direct-dependencies for the code.  That is: if you have `group.php` that uses `user.php`, it should `require_once 'user.php'`, but need not worry about `storage.php` since it isn't directly used, and `user.php` implicitly includes it (that being said - no significant performance disadvantage of being thorough if you wish)

Comment: Thank you Rudi.  So I don't need to require_once for the injection itself to work.

Comment: In your above example you don't need any requires since `$storage` is just a variable - no definitino for `user.php` to need to understand.  If you were using [type hinting][1] (an entirely different topic)... well then you would need to `require` the source that defines the type.
  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php